# Unobtrusive validation without a form tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form which is submitted to a web sevice (via standard AJAX, there's no  tag. I'm using the jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin to validate the fields in this 'form', but I can't get the validation to run.

```
        <div id="form-contact">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtName">Your Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter name" name="txtName" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Your name field is required." />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtEmail">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter email" name="txtEmail" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid email address." data-val-regex-pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&#39;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;&#39;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" data-val-required="Please enter your email address." type="text" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtEmail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtPhone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPhone" placeholder="Enter phone number" name="txtPhone" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Your phone number is required." >
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtPhone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <a id="btnSubmit" href="#">Contact us</a>
        </div>
```

If I manually call `$('#txtName').validate()`, my error message is shown, but I want to do something like `$('#form-contact').validate()` and have the validation called too. Is this possible?

Comment: you can put from but don't add any input type of submit and programmatically trigger submit

Comment: If you want to validate a form, why not use a form?

Answer (score 4):

**Quote OP:**

> *"I want to do something like `$('#form-contact').validate()` and have the validation called too. Is this possible?"*

It's not possible.  Your `#form-contact` element is a `div` and it **must** be a `form`.

The Unobtrusive Validation plugin is dependent upon the jQuery Validate plugin.  You absolutely cannot use the jQuery Validate plugin to validate data from input elements that are not contained within a set of `<form></form>` tags... that's just how the plugin was designed to operate.